# Define qml Object in a c++Function for QtCharts (ChartView)

Tags: c++, function, qml

I would like to create my own specific chart within the ChartView QML-Object. My expectation is to have full flexibility by specifing for example a QCategoryAxis in c++ and than call this function in qml.

First of all I am not quite sure if it is even possible to do like I wish to...
And for my very simple example I get some errors I can't solve.

I would be so glad if anyone could help me out, I am struggling with this QML/C++ combination since two weeks now.

diabchart.h

```
    #ifndef DIABCHART_H
    #define DIABCHART_H

    #include <QtCharts/QChartView>
    #include <QtCharts/QCategoryAxis>
    #include <QObject>

    QT_CHARTS_USE_NAMESPACE

    class DiabChart : public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit DiabChart(QObject *parent = 0);
    public slots:
        Q_INVOKABLE QCategoryAxis* getCategoryAxisY();

    };
```

diabchart.cpp

```
#include "diabchart.h"
#include <QtCharts/QChartView>

QT_CHARTS_USE_NAMESPACE

DiabChart::DiabChart(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{

}

QCategoryAxis* DiabChart::getCategoryAxisY()
{
    // Y-Axis (Bloodsugar)
    QCategoryAxis *axisY = new QCategoryAxis();
    axisY->append("critical", 50);
    axisY->append("low", 70);
    axisY->append("normal", 160);
    axisY->append("high", 250);
    axisY->append("extremly high", 450);
    axisY->setRange(0, 450);
    return axisY;
}
#endif // DIABCHART_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtCharts/QChartView>
#include <QApplication>

#include "diabchart.h"

QT_CHARTS_USE_NAMESPACE

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<DiabChart>("DiabChart", 1, 0, "DiabChart");


    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtCharts 2.0
import DiabChart 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    DiabChart{
        id: xyz
    }

   ChartView{
        title: "Line"
        anchors.fill: parent
        antialiasing: true

        //axes: xyz.getCategoryAxisY()
        //Leads to: Error: Unknown method return type: QCategoryAxis*

        //axes: getCategoryAxisY()
        //Leads to: ReferenceError: getCategoryAxisY is not defined

        //axes: DiabChart.getCategoryAxisY()
        //Leads to: TypeError: Property 'getCategoryAxisY' of object [object Object] is not a function

        ValueAxis{
            id: vlaueAxisX
            min: 0
            max: 24
            tickCount: 12
            labelFormat: "%2.0f:00"
        }

        LineSeries {
            axisX: vlaueAxisX
            axisY: yAxis
            name: "LineSeries"
            XYPoint { id: zero; x: 0; y: 192.6}
            XYPoint { id: first; x: 7; y: 89 }
            XYPoint { x: 9; y: 100 }
            XYPoint { x: 12; y: 50 }
            XYPoint { x: 14; y: 250 }
            XYPoint { x: 18; y: 140 }
            XYPoint { x: 21; y: 80 }
            XYPoint { id: last; x: 23.5; y: 200 }
            XYPoint { id: twentyfour; x: 24; y: 192.6}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to return `QAbstractAxis*`? (QML charts were opened recently and they are new for me too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the answer is to return `QAbstractAxis*`.

To be able to use C++ types in QML, there should be at least a `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE()` for that type somewhere in the source code. Since the Qt itself operates on an `AbstractAxis` QML type (as seen from the qt docs for the charts API), then that's already done for the `QAbstractAxis*`. But the `QCategoryAxis*` is probably not registered.

Comment: and close the question, pls